# Django: updating file

Tags: django

I'm trying to upload a file but once it's uploaded I'm not able to open it since it shows an error saying that there's no an object with that Primary key. I think the error(s) should be in urls or in the path (MEDIA_ROOT) but can't find out what is wrong.

Any suggestion?

**setings.py**

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = "media/"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILES_DIR = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="file_folder/", blank = True, null = True)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
    }),
)
```

**--EDIT--**

I'm using the Admin interface so there's no Views.py

And the traceback is not shown, only the following error:

**ERROR**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/admin/db_personal/foo/3/media/file_folder/django.pdf/
foo object with primary key u'3/media/file_folder/django.pdf' does not exist.
```

Comment: Your description of the error does not seem to have anything to do with files at all, but with database objects. Please show the *actual* error with the full traceback, as well as the upload view.

Comment: I can see the file if I go to : http://localhost:8000/media/file_folder/django.pdf so maybe the problem is in url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEDIA_URL needs to be an absolute path, like STATIC_URL:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Comment: I wasted an hour... :( Thanks Daniel!